# Which App Engine Authentication Method should I choose? (Pros/Cons)

Tags: google-app-engine, comparison, openid, google-account

I am experimenting with Google App Engine and as I went to create an app it asked me to choose an authentication method.  Options are 'Google Account' or 'OpenID', the 'Google Apps Domain' option doesn't interest me.  However, I can't find very much information in the documentation that lists pros/cons of either method.

My question is what are the pros and cons of each of the methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of the exact pros and cons but the biggest is with

- Google Account - the users are forced to have a Google Account
- Open ID - the users must have an account with an Open ID provider which currently are listed [here](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/).

Open ID is how logins on StackOverflow works.

Comment: I'm curious - SO also has a facebook option.  Is that part of OpenID, or separate?  It doesn't show up on the link you gave.

Comment: @brainjam Facebook Connect is similar in that it allows third party websites like StackOverflow and other's to access your Facebook information. You'll notice that if you click that link you will get a Facebook authentication page telling you what data from your facebook account that StackOverflow will have access to.